# Transaction with AngularJS and ASP.NET Web API

Tags: angularjs, transactions, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a small application using AngularJS and ASP.NET Web API. Now the application consists of 2 entities namely Album and Song. The Song entity will have a reference of Album entity.

Now I am wondering what would be the correct way to achieve a Transaction so that when a Album is saved then all the Songs related to that album are saved as well.

Also I was wondering how would the POST method in WebAPI would handle an array of songs (passed as JSON).

```
[ResponseType(typeof(AlbumSong))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMovieSong(AlbumSong albumSong)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.AlbumSongs.Add(albumSong);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = albumSong.Id }, albumSong);
}
```

Can someone please enlighten me on this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all the request in a transaction using an `ActionFilter`.  Something like this:

```
public class TransactionPerRequest : IActionFilter, IDisposable
{
    private TransactionScope transaction;

    private bool isSuccess = false;

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
                    transaction = new TransactionScope(
            TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted });

    }

    void IResultFilter.OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var code = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
        isSuccess = code >= 200 && code <= 399;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            if (isSuccess)
            {
                transaction.Complete();
            }

            transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

As for an array of song you would bind to an array of songs `PostMovieSong(AlbumSong[] albumSongs)` and then use AddRange like `db.AlbumSongs.AddRange(albumSong);`.  However I have to say you shouldn't be passing domain/db entity over the wire.  Consider using a DTO pattern and something like automapper